# JS does not recognize a function in a class

Tags: javascript, methods, p5.js

I have a class with a few methods and they work fine so far but one method is not recognized by the browser and gives the error message "Uncaught ReferenceError: einteilungVonAußenInPunkte is not defined".
i dont see any difference to the other methods and in the console i the method is even listed with the others. Im using the P5.js library btw.

Here is the method in question:

```
    einteilungVonAußenInPunkte(startPunkt, einteilungVonAußen) {

        let arr = [];
        let startPointX = startPunkt.x;
        let startPointY = startPunkt.y;

        let plustStrecke = 0.0;

        let element;
        let einteilungVonAußenReversed = einteilungVonAußen;
        einteilungVonAußenReversed.reverse();

        for (element in einteilungVonAußenReversed) {
            plustStrecke += element;
            let newPoint = createVector(cos(this.kehlGrundWinkel) * plustStrecke + startPointX, startPointY - sin(this.kehlGrundWinkel) * plustStrecke);
            arr.push(newPoint);
        }
        return arr;
    }
```

Thanks for the help!

Comment: Going to need more context. What does the whole class look like? I made a dummy class and function and it worked just fine: `class MyClass {
    einteilungVonAußenInPunkte() {}
}
console.log(new MyClass().einteilungVonAußenInPunkte);`

Comment: Coding in English is considered a good practice. It would make your code easier to read for non German speakers. Otherwise we need more context. It's more likely that's there is something wrong with the class rather than the method

Comment: Please post the code that tries to call `einteilungVonAußenInPunkte`, and mark the line that throws the `ReferenceError`

Comment: `inteilungVonAußenInPunkte is not defined` means you are calling `einteilungVonAußenInPunkte()` as if it's a function, however if it's a method, you need to call `this.einteilungVonAußenInPunkte()` or `someInstance.einteilungVonAußenInPunkte`

Comment: Shame on me. It was the this. seems like i looked a bit too much on the code.
Thanks for the help

Answer (score 1):

hard to tell withtout more context, but on first glance it looks like you're missing the `function` keyword:

```
function einteilungVonAußenInPunkte(startPunkt, einteilungVonAußen) {

        let arr = [];
        let startPointX = startPunkt.x;
        let startPointY = startPunkt.y;

        let plustStrecke = 0.0;

        let element;
        let einteilungVonAußenReversed = einteilungVonAußen;
        einteilungVonAußenReversed.reverse();

        for (element in einteilungVonAußenReversed) {
            plustStrecke += element;
            let newPoint = createVector(cos(this.kehlGrundWinkel) * plustStrecke + startPointX, startPointY - sin(this.kehlGrundWinkel) * plustStrecke);
            arr.push(newPoint);
        }
        return arr;
    }
```

For more info see the [MDN docs](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Guide/Functions)